# GCP logout URL? Unable to configure SSO in AZURE

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, gcloud-compute

I'm trying to setup SSO into Gsuite. I'm able to sign but after logout it shows a logout error bcz of not mentioned logout URL. Can anyone post the GCP logout URL?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not have a logout URL as they do not support SLO. This is not officially documented by Google but you can find it in the documentation of  some IdP's. You can take [this one](https://docs.keeper.io/sso-connect-guide/identity-provider-setup/g-suite-configuration) from Keeper or [this one](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_Single_Logout.htm) from Okta as an example.